# Create placeholder text for wordpress search box

Tags: php

I need to create a search box in my default searchform.php file that has similar behaviour as the default ability in HTML5 with the "placeholder" attribute.

This is what I have in my searchform.php at the moment:

```
 <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="text" />
 <input placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search here..' ); ?>">
```

The text 'Search here..' appears in the input and it dissapeard when I start typeing in the input.
I need it to dissapear when I click the input.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Placeholder by itself will not disappear when you click the text field. I guess you need a bit of Javascript to achieve that.

```
<input type="text" onfocus="if(this.value=='<?php _e( 'Search here..' ); ?>'){this.value='';}" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='<?php _e( 'Search here..' ); ?>';}" value="<?php _e( 'Search here..' ); ?>">
```

Comment: Nowadays & with modern browsers, this can be done in pure CSS, without JS: `input:focus::placeholder { visibility: hidden; }` [see pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoyRVg)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, put it into your theme functions file:

```
function html5_search_form( $form ) { 
     $form = '<section class="search"><form role="search" method="get" id="search-form" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('',  'domain') . '</label>
     <input type="search" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search website" />
     <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Go', 'domain') .'" />
     </form></section>';
     return $form;
}

 add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'html5_search_form' );
```

Just ensure that you change domain to your own language domain.